# How to show that $T|_w^* = (T|_w)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality

Let $T:V \rightarrow V $ linear operator in the inner product space $V$ such that $W$ is subspace of $V$
and for every $T(W) \subset W$ $\quad T^*(W) \subset W$

I am asked to show that  $$T|_w^* = (T|_w)^*$$

so what I did so far is to show that  $T(W^\perp)\in W^\perp$ and $T^*(W^\perp)\subset W^\perp$

How should I procced from here? is what I did is fine or there is no reason to do that?

Comment: they gave us hint that we should show that for every $u \in W^\perp$ there is $T(u)\in W^\perp and T^*(u)\in W^\perp$

Comment: Ok, if $T^*$ is the adjoint wtr to a scalar product. However, what you claim to "have shown" is not true: let $T = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ be a linear map from $R^2$ to $R^2$ and $W$ be the $x$-axis, then $x$-axis is invariant but the orthogonal complement is not.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you mean you want to show that $T^*|_W=(T|_W)^*$?

If so then what you did is unnecessary I think. You should use the fact that if $A$ is a linear operator on $V$, then $A^*$ is characterized by the relation $(Av,w)=(v,A^*w)$ for all $v,w\in V$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the inner product on $V$.

If that's not enough, heres the proof:

> Let $v,w\in W$. Then we have $(T|_W(v),w)=(Tv,w)=(v,T^*w)=(v,T^*|_W(w))$. But we also have $(T|_W(v),w) = (v,(T|_W)^*(w))$ by definition. Since this is true for all $v,w\in W$, we must have $T^*|_W=(T|_W)^*.$

Comment: Firstly I would to thank you for your help, I made a mistake in writing the question, I edited it in the post. is the changes matter your answer?

note: $T(W) \subset W$ $\quad T^*(W) \subset W$ are the correct givens

Comment: I think my answer would stay the same given the edits.